# How do I tell MEF to instantiate a single object for a given type per application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, singleton, mef, repository-pattern

Lets say I have a class called FooController in which I have a property called Bar of type IBar (interface). I need to initialize Bar via MEF. However I need MEF to create only one instance of IBar type for the duration of the application (despite multiple calls to initialize it due to multiple requests) and make it available to all requests concurrently. Note that IBar implementations can be assumed thread safe.

i.e.

```
public interface IBar
{
    string Method();
}

[Export(typeof(IBar))]
public class MyBar: IBar
{
    public string dateTimeCreated;

    public MyBar()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        dateTimeCreated = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " ";
    }

    public string Method()
    {
        return dateTimeCreated;
    }
}

public class FooController : ApiController
{
    [Import(typeof(IBar), RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.Shared)]
    public IBar Bar { get; set; }

    public FooController()
    {
        //Assume CompositionContainer.ComposeParts call here
    }

    public string Get()
    {            
        return Bar.Method();
    }
}
```

The problem is each time I call Get() on FooController, the returned time value changes. This means the MyBar object is being reinstantiated for each call. I basically need it to return the same value meaning I need to tell MEF to create only one instance of IBar in my application despite multiple requests.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `PartCreationPolicy` attribute on your `MyBar` export. Like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IBar))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class MyBar : IBar
{
    // ...
}
```

That also means that you don't need to specify the creation policy on your import:

```
[Import]
public IBar Bar { get; set; }
```

Comment: But this means I have to maintain the CompositionContainer in a static variable and call ComposeParts() on the same container each time. However I've read that the MEF CompositionContainer is not threadsafe. Hence I get an error when multiple threads call ComposeParts on the same container simultaneously. Something along the line "A batch is already being processed". Using the isThreadSafe parameter on the constructor did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET MVC integration of MEF interprets `CreationPolicy.Any` and `CreationPolicy.Shared` as single instance per HTTP request. You need to apply the `ApplicationShared` attribute to the part to share it between HTTP requests.

Update:

The `ApplicationSharedAttribute` can be found in the `System.ComponentModel.Composition.Web.Mvc` assembly. Unfortunately this is not distributed with Framework 4.5. It can be found at the [Using MEF with ASP.NET MVC 3 Sample Code](http://mef.codeplex.com/releases/view/76703) example in the *lib* folder. The drawback is that you will have to reference the composition assemblies found it that sample and not the latest ones.

If you do not want to do that then start with this very simple approach:

1. Add a `CompositionContainer` in your `MvcApplication` class as a `public` property.
2. On the `MvcApplication` constructor create the container and add some catalogs.
3. On the controller get the application from the HttpContext and use one of the `GetExport`/`GetExportedValue`/`GetExportedValues` methods of the `CompositionContainer`. No need to call `ComposeParts` on the container.

There are a lot of other approaches that are more elaborate but this should get you started.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply but I'm having a hard time finding a usage example for this ApplicationShared attribute that you suggested (even an msdn link). Would it be possible for you to specify a usage example or link?

Comment: @Harindaka You will find it in the System.ComponentModel.Composition.Web.Mvc assembly. The "classic" example can be found at http://mef.codeplex.com/releases/view/76703

Comment: I found that System.ComponentModel.Composition.Web.Mvc is deprecated. I'm using MVC 4 and .Net 4.0. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's been a while, but in case you still need it, here is a discussion on how to integrate MEF2 with MVC4: http://mef.codeplex.com/discussions/389317